# Is it possible to do Coverage for a Windows Service for DevPartner Studio Professional Edition?

Tags: windows-services, code-coverage, devpartner

I am task to use DevPartner Studio Professional Edition Release 10.5.3. I am trying to verify if there is really no way to do Coverage for a Windows Service Application for this?

Basically the Coverage tools executes a process within itself. Can the process still be coveraged within the scope of the Windows Service?

The Windows Service I would like to coverage is on code using Visual Basic .NET 2008

Comment: You can use [OpenCover](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover) to get CodeCoverage results of a service.

Other commercial tools such as [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/) should also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the document "Understanding DevPartner.PDF", which you can access from DPS's "InfoCenter" application, there is a topic "Starting Analysis from the Command Line".  With the instructions found there it is possible to collect performance data from a service.  That said, I've not done it myself, as almost my entire focus on the product has been on the BoundsChecker (Error Detection) component.

Drop us a line at our product forum at http://community.microfocus.com/, and more of our group will be able to chime in on this topic.